# Kafka cluster on docker - not able to connect with one of the node from application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Using attached docker compose create a Kafka cluster of two nodes. It is up and running All cluster information is visible through kafka-ui application (also deployed on docker) using internal ports.

However I am not able to connect my producer consumer applications properly using external ports.

Docker compose -

```html
version: "3"

services: 
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: c-kafka-ui
    ports:
      - "9003:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: c-kafka1:29092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_NAME: secondlocal
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: c-kafka2:29093
    depends_on:
      - c-kafka1
      - c-kafka2
            
  c-zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    container_name: "c-zookeeper"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "c-zookeeper:/data"
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  
  c-kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    container_name: c-kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "c-kafka1:/data"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://c-kafka1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: c-zookeeper:2181
      # Assign rack to each broker
      broker.rack: rack-1
    depends_on:
      - c-zookeeper
      
  c-kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    container_name: c-kafka2
    ports:
      - "9093:9092"
    volumes:
      - "c-kafka2:/data"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://:29093,EXTERNAL://:9093"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://c-kafka2:29093,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: "INTERNAL"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: c-zookeeper:2181
      # Assign rack to each broker
      broker.rack: rack-2
    depends_on:
      - c-zookeeper

volumes:
  c-zookeeper:
    driver: local
  c-kafka1:
    driver: local
  c-kafka2:
    driver: local
```

Producer and consumer config -

```html
spring.kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092,localhost:9093
  producer:
    key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: "*"

spring.kafka.consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093,localhost:9092
  key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  group-id: RACK_EXPERIMENT_GROUP
  properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: "*"
```

Producer exception -

```html
2023-10-16T23:14:08.925+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 36 due to node 2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 3ms, elapsed time since send: 3ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
2023-10-16T23:14:09.872+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 2 disconnected.
2023-10-16T23:14:09.872+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 38 due to node 2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 4ms, elapsed time since send: 4ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
2023-10-16T23:14:10.898+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 2 disconnected.
2023-10-16T23:14:10.898+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 40 due to node 2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 2ms, elapsed time since send: 2ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
2023-10-16T23:14:11.724+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 2 disconnected.
2023-10-16T23:14:11.725+05:30  INFO 98624 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 42 due to node 2 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 2ms, elapsed time since send: 2ms, request timeout: 3600000ms)
```

Consumer exception -

```html
2023-10-16T23:37:42.872+05:30 TRACE 99172 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-RACK_EXPERIMENT_GROUP-1, groupId=RACK_EXPERIMENT_GROUP] Skipping fetch for partition EXPERIMENT-1 because previous request to localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) has not been processed
```